# How to find the highest possible number of quantity in both categories?

Tags: linear-programming

This question seemed pretty easy to me, but I have the wrong answer according to my textbook.

```
In a graduating class of 236 students, 142 took algebra and 121 took chemistry. 
What is the greatest possible number of students that could have taken both?
```

If all 121 students in chem took both classes, that would leave `121 + (142-121) = 142` which is much smaller than our graduating size, so not all students in Chemistry can be in both. My answer was 27, since

```
1 = P(algebra) + P(chemistry) - P(both)
```

Where I figured `P(both) = 27/236` since `P(algebra) + P(chemistry) = 263/236`

But the book is telling me the actual answer is 121. What is the right way to determine the greatest possible number of things participating in 2 categories?

Comment: Why cant 121 have taken both?

Comment: Case of greatest number: anyone who took chemistry also took algebra. Your mistake is that there can exist people who took neither chemistry nor algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculated the **smallest** possible number of students that could have taken both.

It could be that $121$ students took both algebra and chemistry, another $21$ took algebra, but not chemistry, and the remaining $94$ took **neither**.

(the question doesn't say each student took at least one of the two courses!)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To solve this problem you want the greatest possible value of $x$. It is clear from the diagram that $x$ cannot be greater than $142$ nor greater than $121$, otherwise or would be negative. Hence, $x$ must be less than or $142−x, 121−x$ equal to $121$. Since there is no information to exclude the correct $x=121$

Answer (score 0):

Your problem belongs to linear programming. Linear programming is a technique of maximizing or minimizing a linear function subject to linear constraints and inequalities.

Let's convert your problem to a linear programming problem. This goes along the lines of @absolute friend's answer. The cardinality (number of elements) of any subset of students is non-strictly positive (non-negative). This means that:

- the number of students that took algebra and chemistry is non-strictly positive, $x\geq 0$,
- the number of students that took algebra but not chemistry is non-strictly positive, $142-x\geq 0$, equivalently, $142\geq x$,
- the number of students that took chemistry but not algebra is non-strictly positive, $121-x\geq 0$, equivalently, $121\geq x$,
- the number of students that took neither algebra nor chemistry is non-strictly positive, $236-142-(121-x)\geq 0$, equivalently, $x\geq 27$.

All these constraints are equivalent to $27\leq x\leq 121$. You need to maximize $x$. Obviously, the greatest value of $x$ satisfying the constraints is $121$. Minimization is similar.

Of course, not all linear programming problems are so easy.